# Get Records Before and After Date

Tags: sql, partitioning

Let's say I have the following data set:

| Unique ID | Admission Date | Release Date | Identifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | 7/1/22 | 7/4/22 | 1 |
| 456 | 7/6/22 | 7/9/22 | 2 |
| 456 | 6/20/22 | 6/25/22 | 2 |
| 456 | 6/15/22 | 6/18/22 | 2 |

I want to pull only the first, second, and third rows using SQL. This is based on the identifier and date columns. I always want to pull in any rows where identifier = 1. And then I only want the rows that have identifier = 2 when they are either directly before or after the row with identifier =1. (ie, the row before is when the release date is < admission date with identifier =1. The row after is when the admission date > release date with identifier = 1).

I think this solution will involve a partition, but I've never had to use it get rows before and after.

Comment: On which technology do you need code?

Comment: SQL, sorry. I edited the question. Are you able to see the table? When I post it shows correctly, but when I see the actual post the table doesn't exist.

Comment: Edited again. It's based on admission date > release date when identifier or release date < admission date with identifier = 1 always being the comparison

Comment: I don't follow at all. Far as I can see, there is no row "directly before or after the row with identifier =1". Also, how come the `Unique ID` is not unique? And please tag your dbms